# accessing JSON properties in REST API response

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to access the 'items' array in a response I get using the 'get' function in the 'request' node module. As you can see below I get the entire response and can log it to the console, but when I try to access the 'items' property within that response it says it's undefined:

```
console.log("r.body: " + r.body);
```

response:`r.body: {"limit":-1,"totalCount":1,"items":[{"id":1958,"status":"PULLED"...`

```
console.log("r.body: " + r.body.items);j
```

response: `undefined`

Comment: Are you sure `r.body` isn't stringified JSON? `var response = JSON.parse(r.body); console.log(response.items);`

Comment: That was right it works, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid parsing the response each time (`JSON.parse(response.body)`) you can use the `defaults` method to tell the request module to always parse the JSON. like so:

```
var req = request.defaults({
  json: true
})
```

This is useful if you are repeatedly communicating with an API.